# Convert batch file to VB Script

Tags: batch-file, user-interface, vbscript, cmd

A troubled IT Technician looking for help here! I have 2 batch files that I need to put a GUI to instead of the end user just looking at the cmd line, therefore I need to convert the code to VB. Here's the two pieces of code that I have to tried to convert without success:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Contract Folder Creator v0.99
ECHO -----------------------------
ECHO.
ECHO Please enter the Client name:
SET /P CLIENT=
ECHO.
ECHO Please enter the Job name:
SET /P JOB=
ECHO.
\\server\Archive\psexec \\server "A:\NewContractBE.cmd" %CLIENT% %JOB% > NUL
```

Second File:

```
@ECHO OFF
ROBOCOPY "C:\Administration\New Sales Folder" "C:\Contracts\%1\%2" /E /COPY:DAT > NUL
MKDIR "A:\Contracts\%1\%2\Not Backed Up" > NUL
MKDIR "A:\Contracts\%1\%2\Not Backed Up\Other Documents" > NUL
MKDIR "A:\Contracts\%1\%2\Not Backed Up\Pictures" > NUL
MKLINK /J "C:\Contracts\%1\%2\Not Backed Up" "A:\Contracts\%1\%2\Not Backed Up" > NUL
ECHO Done!
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Many thanks,
Joe

Comment: This runs your commands a line at a time (or batch files or any program) in a hidden command window. `Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"):
WshShell.Run "cmd /k dir c:\windows\*.*", 0, false)`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. :)

I would need it to be visible because the user needs to input data.

Comment: Can't help thosethat won't ne helped.

Answer (score 1):

An idea :

```
@echo off
call :Digita_box "Please enter the Client name:" "Contract Folder Creator v0.99"
set "Client=Digita_"
call :Digita_box "Please enter the JOB name:" "Contract Folder Creator v0.99"
set "Job=Digita_"
ECHO.
\\server\Archive\psexec \\server "A:\NewContractBE.cmd" %CLIENT% %JOB% > NUL
pause >nul
exit /b

:Digita_Box
set Digita_=
set Sub_Tit=%~2
set Mensa=%~1
echo wscript.echo inputbox(WScript.Arguments(0),WScript.Arguments(1)) >"%temp%\Digita_.vbs"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\Digita_.vbs" "%Mensa%" "%Sub_Tit%"') do set Digita_=%%a
exit /b
```